# If I use Google Web Fonts on my site, will fonts be displayed properly?

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I mean this font collection: https://www.google.com/fonts

I want to use some maybe non standart fonts on my page. If I use Google Web Fonts on my site, will fonts be displayed properly? Or fonts from user's browser will be displayed? Or nothing will be displayed? Thank you.

Comment: Google Web Fonts will be properly displayed on your site.

Comment: If you do it correctly, fonts *should* be displayed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[caniuse @ fontface](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface) – yes, you can, all modern browsers supports `fontface`.

Comment: Thank you. 1 question. I have to copy past link from google fonts site to `<head>`, create `@font-face` construction and then I can use font, right?

Comment: Yes. Google generates `@font-face` for you and gives you `<link>` to insert on site. The last step is just to use font as showns Google.

Answer (score 2):

The font you load will be used on all clients as long as the file from Google is available and the client understands this technology. Therefore you should not load too many fonts, because it dramatically slows down the page loading, as font files are pretty large.

Since you can specify multiple fonts in css, if the file is not available the second specification will be used. This should be something like "Arial", which is mainly available. The third specification can be something generic like "sans-serif". This assures that at least any font you want is used.

Nevertheless, the client will use any font if nothing appropriate was found. It will never silently display no text, just because your CSS does not specify something usable.

Answer (score 1):

**yes it will displayed properly and perfectly** on web

so no need to worry, use it freely